# android - create new contact with photo from own application

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts

I want to open Native Contacts editor from my own application via intent,  with data I put with the intent (using putExtra functions).
I use ContactsContract.Intents.Insert to pass data to Native contacts. I can pass all contact data (address, name, number, etc.) but not the contact photo.

How do I do that (passing either actual data bytes or url)?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet you can try:

```
public static void setContactPhoto(ContentResolver c,
                                   byte[] bytes,
                                   long personId) {
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  int photoRow = -1;
  String where = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = "
    + personId + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
    + "=='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";
  Cursor cursor = c.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                          null, where,
                          null, null);
  int idIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data._ID);
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    photoRow = cursor.getInt(idIdx);
  }
  cursor.close();

  values.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, personId);
  values.put(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1);
  values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, bytes);
  values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

  if (photoRow >= 0) {
    c.update(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values,
             ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = " + photoRow, null);
  } else {
    c.insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
  }
}
```

You can read all about the details from the [source](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/30/handling-contact-photos-all-api-levels/) of that article.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer my question. I don't want insert a contact to Native DB, I want to open Native Contacts in View or Edit mode, by sending intent with the relevant data, including the photo.